# What filesystem comes closest to matching NTFS for support of ACLs, and highly-granular permissioning?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, filesystems, ldap, access-control-list

It seems that most other filesystems handle the basic *nix permissions (ugo±rwx), with maybe an addition here or there. Or can be "made" to handle ACLs through the use of other tools on top of the system.

On the wikipedia pages about filesystems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems &
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems), it appears that while some *do* support extended meta-data, none support natively the level of permissioning that NTFS does.

Am I wrong in this understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZFS has a good support for enhanced ACLs. Check out the documentation: [Solaris ZFS Administration Guide: Chapter 8 Using ACLs to Protect ZFS Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/ftyxi.html#scrolltoc)

Maybe this is something you're searching for. :-)

Comment: thanks - looks like it's the closest to what I'm looking for - cross platform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Platforms), and [fairly] widely used

Answer (score 1):

XFS has built in support for filesystem acls and extended attributes.