# What good Active Directory + Exchange competition is there?

Tags: active-directory, email, ldap, access-control-list

Based on this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/84370/) regarding enhanced permission support in filesystems, what is the best permissions + directory and mail stack to compare against Active Directory on NTFS with Exchange?

I'm familiar with [OpenLDAP](http://OpenLDAP.org) for directory services, and [Scalix](http://scalix.com/) for email and calendaring. Are there other good competitors in this arena? Novell's NetWare would have been my answer a decade ago, but with that having pretty much disappeared, I haven't seen a good replacement, outside of "perl-and-duct-tape".

ie - is there an integrated packaging of these (or other) toolsets?

The thrust of this question is to see how plausible a completely AD-free environment is, with a quality calendar, email, and directory services functionality.

It can run on Mac OS X, Linux, or Windows - I'm just very interested to see what others have done/seen/used in this area.

Comment: related question - http://serverfault.com/questions/5282

Comment: I am not sure I would count on scalix any more. Their last forum post which is moderated to post was in july of last year.  I have been looking for the community files as thier website hasen't worked for me in over 6 months to get new files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as Directory Services go, you've allready mentioned the main competitor to AD, Open LDAP. A couple more I know of are:

- [Red Hat Directory Services](http://www.redhat.com/directory_server/) and its [Fedora Alternative](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/)
- [Apache Directory](http://directory.apache.org/)
- [Apple Open Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Open_Directory)

As far as Exchange alternatives go, you might want to look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/5282) but some of the most popular are:

- [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/)
- [Open-Xchange](http://www.open-xchange.com/)
- [Kerio Mail Server](http://www.kerio.com/mailserver)

Comment: I've used Open-Xchange in years past and it was pretty good back then.  Zimbra looked very promising, but never got the chance to deploy it.

Comment: freeIPA is I believe the successor RH directory services.

Answer (score 4):

NetWare may have disappeared (almost), but eDirectory and GroupWise are still very much around, and will run quite happily on either Server 200* or Linux.

Answer (score 3):

OES2 from Novell is the replacement for Netware, and it maintains the NSS filesystem on Linux (SLES Specifically) that has excellent ACL and inheritance abilities.

eDirectory is a good competitor to Active Directory for directory services.

Comment: I migrated my company from Netware to Microsoft about 5 years ago.  Netware had a rockin directory service.  If only they'd had the aggressive marketing tactics that MS had...

Comment: Totally agree. They really explored and defined much of that space with what was in many ways a superior and more stable product than MS's equivalent offering at the time. It's a shame that lesser marketing is what it came down to.